# Is the following recursive sequence $a_n$ positive definite?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Is the following recursive sequence $a_n$ positive definite?
>
> $a_1=1\hspace{25pt}a_{n+1}= 2a_n +1$

---

I've been asked to prove also that's strictly increasing, both things by induction.

Considering that we want to prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $a_n$ is stricly increasing i.e. $a_{n+1}> a_n$

1. For $n=1$ we've that $3=a_2>a_1=1$ is true
2. We assume $a_{n+1}> a_n$ true by inductive hypothesis and
3. We prove it for $(n+1)$ then:

   $a_{n+2}> a_{n+1} \Leftrightarrow$

   $2a_{n+1} +1 > 2a_{n}+1 \Leftrightarrow$

   $a_{n+1} > a_{n} $

   then is true $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, I'm struggling with the other part that probably is the easiest but since I'm new to induction I'm not sure how to proceed.

We want to prove that $a_n$ is positive definite i.e. $ a_n>0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

1. For $n=1$ we've that $1=a_1>0$ is true
2. We assume $a_{n}> 0$ true by inductive hypothesis and
3. We prove it for $(n+1)$ then:

   $a_{n+1}>0 \Leftrightarrow$

   $2a_n +1 >0 $

And now what?

Comment: If you already know that $(a_n)$ is increasing then $a_n > 0$ follows from that, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. But how do I write that properly?

Comment: Well, the induction step is $a_n > 0 \implies a_{n+1} \ge a_n > 0$ ...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get why that is increasing implies its greater than zero.

Comment: It’s not just that it’s increasing, it also starts at $1$ if that helps.

Comment: Add $1$ to both sides of the recurrence relation, and prove by induction the explicit formula $a_n+1=2^{n-1}.$